# React-native fs stops other async functions to execute until the file downloads

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, react-native-fs

I am using react-native fs to download the file. The react-native fs uses promises, so until the promise is returned back it keeps other async functions in a queue to execute. For instance, If i start downloading a file then other async functions(such as getting data from local storage) gets blocked. The other async function starts executing only when the download is complete.

any help would be appreciated.